# google maps v3 store locator

Tags: php, xml, google-maps-api-3

I know, there are already lots of blogs for "store locator", but I couldn't find an answer. I used the tutorial from https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3. Things are not working, so does anybody have problems with that tutorial getting the store locator working?
My problem is, that no valid xml-file is produced. I've changed the xml-output, because the original one did not work at all. Here are the codes for the two files:

### Heading ##1. http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_2a.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Example</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var map;
var markers = [];
var infoWindow;
var locationSelect;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52, 8),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (markerNum != "none"){
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    }
  };
}

function searchLocations() {
 var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
   } else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
}

function clearLocations() {
 infoWindow.close();
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   markers[i].setMap(null);
 }
 markers.length = 0;

 locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
 var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.value = "none";
 option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
 locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}

function searchLocationsNear(center) {
 clearLocations();

 var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
 var searchUrl = 'ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' +  center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
   var xml = parseXml(data);
   var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
     var nachname = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Nachname");
     var strasse = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("strasse");
     var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

     createOption(nachname, distance, i);
     createMarker(latlng, nachname, strasse);
     bounds.extend(latlng);
   }
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
   locationSelect.onchange = function() {
     var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
     google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
   };
  });
}

function createMarker(latlng, nachname, strasse) {
  var html = "<b>" + nachname + "</b> <br/>" + strasse;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

function createOption(name, distance, num) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = num;
  option.innerHTML = nachname + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
<div>
 <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>
<select id="radiusSelect">
  <option value="25" selected>25mi</option>
  <option value="100">100mi</option>
  <option value="200">200mi</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
</div>
<div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Heading ## 2. http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
require("dbpass.php");
if (PHP_VERSION>='5')
require_once('domxml-php4-to-php5.php');
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET['lat'];
$center_lng = $_GET['lng'];
$radius = $_GET['radius'];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);

$connection=mysql_connect ($dbhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the ASPE table
$query = sprintf("SELECT strasse, nachname, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM ASPE HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

//header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$node = $dom->create_element("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);
$newnode->set_attribute("nachname", utf8_encode ($row['nachname']));
$newnode->set_attribute("strasse", utf8_encode ($row['strasse']));
$newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);
$newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
$newnode->set_attribute("radius", $row['radius']);
}
//echo $dom->saveXML();

$xmlfile = $doc->dump_file("codierung.xml");
?>
```

That might be correct, but: it sends me to lat/lng 0.000000/0.000000 (South Pacific), which could mean, that geocoding doesn't work properly. But furthermore, no datasets will be filled in the xml, even when adding lat, lng and radius to the URL (e.g. http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php?lat=56.45&lng=6.45&radius=25).

May anyone validate the code? Or could anyone please show me a working example with that store locator, if possible with scripting code?

Many thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Invalid query: Unknown column 'address' in 'field list'

Comment: I would suggest returning JSON instead of XML. You can use something like jQuery to parse it.

Comment: When I increase the radius to 2500 in http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php?lat=56.45&lng=6.45&radius=2500 It shows up the following error

Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object in /homepages/38/d19233472/htdocs/U&I/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php on line 47

Comment: I got worked this, but how can i check if there is no stores in particular locations

Answer (score 0):

Your [Url](http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php?lat=56.45&lng=6.45&radius=25) shows   Invalid query: Unknown column 'address' in 'field list' 
If all the nodes equate to field name you should generate XML 
[image: Table]

Does your table look like this or have you changed the field names?
I have a [demo](http://daviestrachan.zxq.net/maps/stationmap8.php) based on the tutorial. It is based on UK (Try London) but defaults safely if address outside UK are tried (tryParis).

If no record are found the map will default to 0,0 (Central Pacific). To default to the location use the following code.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("nachname", "No Records Found");
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $center_lat);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $center_lng);
    }
else {
    Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $node = $dom->create_element("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);
    $newnode->set_attribute("nachname", utf8_encode ($row['nachname']));
    $newnode->set_attribute("strasse", utf8_encode ($row['strasse']));
    $newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);    
    $newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
    $newnode->set_attribute("radius", $row['radius']);
   }
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your post. You have created a great demo, that works really fine - and even for Paris, if you choose 200 miles as radius ;-))you're right, I've changed the field names using "nachname" instaed of "name" and "strasse" instaed of "address" - however, I adjusted that in the scripting. And as the radius-function uses lat and lng, the address-field is not in use for any geocoding, right? I've added the codes for both files in my original question. Maybe you could find my mistake? Or may you mail me your scriptings? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are still not generating in XML http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php?lat=56.45&lng=6.45&radius=25 . Check your query using phpMyAdmin for example

Comment: Hi David,  thanks a lot for your help! I found some "little" mistakes, which caused some (but not all) trouble. So, I mixed "$node = $doc->create_element("markers");" with "$node = $dom->create_element("marker");". That's why I didn't get any xml. Now, xml is created! BUT: There's something wrong with the radius. If I put it in at http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php?lat=51.45&lng=6.45&radius=25 it says, that the index "radius" is undefined. I wonder why...May distance and radius be mixed up? Well, I'll go through it again...Maybe you've an idea...Thanks a lot

Comment: "radius" is undefined. indicates that radius has not been passed from calling page. Hard coding the url shows the fault so it is in     http://umwelt-und-information.com/maps/ASPE_Adressen_kodieren_3a.php. The most probable fault is     $radius = $_GET['radius']; you can hard code  $radius =200  to see if that is the problem

Comment: I got worked this, but how can i check if there is no stores in particular locations

Answer (score 0):

consider the pesence of international charater format ASCII 
insteady of header("Content-type: text/xml");
put this
header("Content-type: text/xml charater utf-8");
the the xml file will genereted when you run the second file only and 
assing value to lat,lng and radius